# How can I make my ubercart catalog content available to users?

Tags: ubercart

I can't make my ubercart catalog content available to logged in users.

They can see the catalog **page title** but not the products.

This is what a logged in User can see:

[image]

This is my catalog views settings:

[image]
What I tried: I changed the rights for users already as shown below. Nothing happens.

[image]

What else am I missing?

Comment: Are you sure the Product nodes are published? Can authenticated users see individual Product nodes?

Comment: @WimMostrey I just tried your suggestion.. No users can't see the individual product nodes. How do I publish individual nodes? I already made the individiual products available "published" but it doesn't seem do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you mention that authenticated users can't access your Product nodes, it's most likely that your nodes aren't published, or that there is a module interfering with the access check.

**First**, check if your nodes are actually published, on the Create or Edit form:

[image]

**Second**, go to `/admin/people/permissions` and check if anonymous users have the `View published content` permission.

[image]

**Third**, are you using any modules like [Node Access](https://www.drupal.org/project/node_access) that might alter the access permissions?

Comment: Thanks a lot Wim. Third Option solved the problem!! Node Access was infact not giving access to users. I changed the permissions for my node content type (products in my case) and then drupal asked me on my front page to globally reconstruct all permissions. After this it worked. (btw, i tried to award you the bounty but i have to wait 22 hours for it ;) )

Comment: I'm glad to hear that! Bonne chance avec ton site de e-commerce.